# Nome sobre a imagem quando mouse passa css

Tags: css

Preciso colocar o nome da imagem sobre ela quando o mouse passar. O mesmo efeito que temos usando o :hover quando o mouse passa por cima. Quero fazer o nome da imagem aparecer, colocar negrito, tamanho da fonte, etc.

Comment: Aproveita que é usuário novo e faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do funcionamento do site. Depois, pressione [edit] e adicione o seu código, descrevendo qual foi a dificuldade encontrada.

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo básico com algumas poucas alterações retirado do site [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)

Na classe `.text` você tem a opção de mudar a *cor,fonte,tamanho* e aplicar todo e qualquer estilo que você achar necessário.

```
.text {
  color: #008CBA; // Muda a cor do texto
  font-size: 30px; // Muda o tamanho da fonte
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Esse é apenas um dos estilos criados pela equipe W3. Existem alguns outros efeitos hover que você pode encontrar [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp).

Podemos encontrar não só esse como muitos outros efeitos 'comuns' na sessão [HOW TO](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp) do W3.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.text {
  color: #008CBA;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://illustratd.com/uploads/GNyhX565Mo__450x450.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">Sorriso.jpg</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a formatação com negrito não for tão importante, você pode adicionar os atributos `alt` e `title` à imagem. I.e.:

```
<img src="imagem.png" title="Ó o gás!" alt="Pessoas dançando para uma meme.">
```

O atributo `title` faz com que a imagem use o *tooltip* próprio do navegador, enquanto o atributo `alt` é utilizado quando a imagem não pode ser renderizada (por erro na hora de carregar ou quando a página é carregada em navegador não-gráfico).

Além de exigir pouco código, ser *cross-browser* por padrão e não interferir na folha de estilo, essa forma garante que sua página fica mais acessível a pessoas com deficiência visual. Os navegadores podem ler em voz alta o texto do atributo `alt` quando a pessoa selecionar a imagem, por exemplo.

Agora, se você precisa mesmo enfeitar o texto, [a resposta do Bsalvo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/222122/1658) tem a solução mais apropriada.

Comment: Acho que você queria dizer o atributo: `title`, não? O `alt` não cria o efeito desejado.

Comment: @LeonFreire tem razão. Obrigado, vou ajustar a resposta :)