# Como sobrepor imagem com um background transparente?

Tags: html, css, html5

Eu tenho uma imagem em um img e quero colocar um background preto sobre ela, para a imagem ficar escura, eu vou usar isso em um :hover, eu já coloquei um div sobre ela com background preto.

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

mas não aparece nada.

Comment: De uma olhada na minha resposta, é exatamente o que você precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222088/nome-sobre-a-imagem-quando-mouse-passa-css/222122#222122

Comment: @Bsalvo se é exatamente a mesma coisa, você pode sinalizar como duplicata.

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa, o texto aparece sobre a imagem, essa parte eu sei fazer, mas a o background não aparece, se eu tirar a imagem ele aparece.